# How to properly use JQuery Option Selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm learning JQuery and need some assistance with the change function. This example works fine by appending the value to the word example.

```
var val = $('#exampleFruit').val();
$('#example'+val).show();
```

Working - https://jsfiddle.net/wj_fiddle_playground/mt69f5w4/19/

However, now I'm trying to use the optionValue variabile with value attribute like this.

```
$(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
```

Not Working - https://jsfiddle.net/wj_fiddle_playground/tavg9ec7/11/

If `<option value="1">Apple</option>`  is chosen the apple dropdown should show..etc.

**UPDATE**

If the apple list is `<select id="option2Apple">` and the option value is
`<option value="1">Apple</option>`

How do I choose table row 3 from apple?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wj_fiddle_playground/tavg9ec7/18/

```
<table>
  <tr id="table 1">
   <select id="exampleFruit">
  <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="2">Banana</option>
</select>
</tr>

  <tr id="table 2">
  <select id="option1Banana" class="exampleSubselect" style="display: none;">
  <option value="1">Plantain</option>
  <option value="2">Burro</option>
  <option value="3">Cavendish</option>
  </select>
</tr>

  <tr id="table 3">
   <select id="option2Apple" class="exampleSubselect" style="display: none;">
 <option value="1">Red Delicious</option>
  <option value="2">Granny Smith</option>
  <option value="3">Cox's Orange Pippin</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget "#" this is for get the id's in jQuery. Try modifying this:

```
<select id="exampleFruit">
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="exampleApple">Apple</option>
    <option value="exampleBanana">Banana</option>
    <option value="exampleOrange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#exampleFruit").change(function(){
      var optionValue = $(this).val();
      $('.exampleSubselect').hide();
      if(optionValue){
        $(`#${optionValue}`).show();
      }
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: Did you test this in the OP's fiddle?

Comment: I tried it here https://jsfiddle.net/wj_fiddle_playground/tavg9ec7/11/

Answer (score 1):

something like that:

```
$("#exampleFruit option").each(function() {
  var optionValue = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues in your code. Firstly `$('exampleFruit')` is missing the preceding `#` id selector. Also, the value of the option elements is `1`, `2` and `3`, yet you appear to be requiring the fruit names as a string. In that case you need to use `text()`, not `val()`. Finally, only 1 `option` can be selected at a time so the `each()` loop isn't necessary.

In addition it would follow logically that you want to hide the previously selected fruit options when one is changed. To do that you can use `hide()`.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#exampleFruit").change(function() {
    let optionValue = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    $('.exampleSubselect').val('1').hide();
    $('#example' + optionValue).show();
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="table 1">
    <select id="exampleFruit">
      <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
      <option value="1">Apple</option>
      <option value="2">Banana</option>
      <option value="3">Orange</option>
    </select>
  </tr>

  <tr id="table 2">
    <select id="exampleApple" class="exampleSubselect" style="display: none;">
      <option value="1">Red Delicious</option>
      <option value="2">Granny Smith</option>
      <option value="3">Cox's Orange Pippin</option>
    </select>
  </tr>
  <tr id="table 3">
    <select id="exampleBanana" class="exampleSubselect" style="display: none;">
      <option value="1">Plantain</option>
      <option value="2">Burro</option>
      <option value="3">Cavendish</option>
    </select>
  </tr>
  <tr id="table 4">
    <select id="exampleOrange" class="exampleSubselect" style="display: none;">
      <option value="1">Blood</option>
      <option value="2">Navel</option>
      <option value="3">>Valencia</option>
    </select>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory.  I should have been a little bit more specific.  How do I select without using example + option value.  I will update the question.

Comment: You can't. You need to concatenate the selector string using the value from the selected option.